# How to pull Excel file path using Outlook VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I am trying to create a macro in Outlook to pull the file path for the open Excel workbook into a hyperlink in my email.

For example, if a workbook with file path "C:\Desktop\Documents\Phones.xlsx" was open, there would be a link created in my email to that workbook.

Comment: I think main problem would be detecting which workbook is opened at that time. Besides. what happens if there is more than 1 workbook opened? Consider doing the reverse way. From an active Workbook, send an e-mail withe hyperlink of the workbook itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the link to be the body of the email this should make it.

```
Sub hyperlink_zu_email()

'get path of active document
   
    Dim spath As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim scomplete As String
   
    spath = Excel.Application.ActiveDocument.Path
    sname = Excel.Application.ActiveDocument.Name
    scomplete = Excel.Application.ActiveDocument.Path + "\" + Application.ActiveDocument.Name

'send Email

    Dim mailmsg As Object
    Dim OutLkApp As Object
   
    Set OutLkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mailmsg = OutLkApp.CreateItem(0)
    With mailmsg
    .To = "he@do.at"
    .Subject = scomplete
    .HTMLBody = "<a href='file:///" & scomplete & "'>" & sname & "</a>"
    .Display
    End With
   
End Sub
```

The "sname" part can be whatever you want, in this case it would take the name of the active document. This is what the link looks like for the guy who gets the mail.

But as @Foxfire And Burns And Burns mentioned, it will only work correctly if there is only one workbook opened.